# Image upload to service issue with f5 firewall

Tags: c#, api, web

I recently faced an issue with a firewall called **f5**,
the issue began when I uploaded an image, check the attached image.

the firewall blocks the stream of bytes.

so I don't know if the problem is in my code or in the firewall.

to be sure that my code has no problem I made an mvc application to test upload and in fiddler the same symbols appeared

These are the WAF Errors: 
1. HTTP protocol compliance failure - the request was having a NULL , which could cause buffer overflow issues. 
2. Failed to convert character - F5 is not able to understand the data after decoding the HTTP traffic and is blocking it.

**fiddler capture for mvc upload**
[image: fiddler capture for mvc upload]

**Firewall Error Image**
[image: Firewall Error Image]

Comment: It says the firewall blocked it, why don't you try to figure out *why*?

Comment: If the firewall is blocking the data, then the firewall is the one with the problem, talk to your system administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but the system administrator says that the buffer content of the image sent is not accepted because it might cause either attacks or buffer overflow,t and he prove his point by copying the buffer into a word document and tell me look its 40 pages or so!! is there any other solution to send an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your seeing is F5's WAF (Web Application Firewall), and its blocking the request because something in the request is not matching up with the defined policy of the application.  Can you screen shot just below, the general details section, this will usually include the reason for the block (the violations that occurred).

To answer the second part of your question, the symbols are the F5 reversing the encoding, and trying to show you the real characters being sent, this is to get around possible double, triple, etc encoding attacks.

Comment: i edited my question with WAF erros, but this means that i'm sending requests in a wrong way? i tried every possible sample on planet earth and it didnt work.

Comment: There is most likely nothing wrong with your code, the policy itself on the F5 seems to be tuned incorrectly, causing the block to occur.  If you can by pass (go around the F5) and everything tests, then they will need to adjust the ASM policy to allow your request through.